# clang-format space before attribute

Tags: c++17, clang-format

We are using `clang-format` to format our C++17-supporting code base and we would like to add a space before an attribute that appertains to a variable:

```
int x[[maybe_unused]] = foo(); // clang-format 6 does this
int y [[maybe_unused]] = bar(); // we'd like this
```

Does anyone know how to make the appropriate adjustments to get that extra space?  I've not found any field that I can set in my `.clang-format` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved with `clang-format` 7.